# Local changing of MathJax font

Tags: support, formatting

I'm preferring the **STIX** font for rendering the MathJax formulas. But in the Math.SE there are the `TeX` font set as preferred.

Is there any way to make local use **STIX** font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: install the STIX fonts locally on your system. MathJax will automatically use local fonts if available.

Comment: Is there any example where both fonts are used, so I can check? I've installed the **STIX** fonts but I'm in doubt if MathJax in Chrome uses it.

Comment: Right click on a MathJax formula, and click "About MathJax".